# java how do i read a negative int as a positive one

Tags: java, arrays, sum

The question at hand is:

> The method should compute for each row the sum of the absolute values
>   of the elements of that row. The method should return the maximum of
>   these sums. For example, if applied to the test array, the method
>   should return the value max (3+1+4+0,5+9+2+6, 5+3+7+8) = max (8,22,23)
>   = 23.

The test array:

```
3 -1  4  0
5  9 -2  6 
5  3  7 -8
```

so far i have made a method that gets the value of all the rows and returns to me the sum in a list; however, i want it to turn negative integers into positive ones.
here's my code so far:

```
public static int[] rowSums(int[][]array) {
int[] a = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        int sum = IntStream.of(array[i]).sum();
        a[i]=sum;


} return a;}
```

Output:

```
[6,18,7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Math#abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-)(standing for absolute value) which converts any negative number into a positive number:

```
int sum = IntStream.of(array[i]).map(Math::abs).sum();
```

If you'd like to lose those for-loops, you can even just stick with streams:

```
public static int[] rowSums(int[][] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .mapToInt(i -> Arrays.stream(i).map(Math::abs).sum())
                 .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use the Map. So The code will  be like this.

```
public static int[] rowSums(int[][]array) {
int[] a = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        int sum = IntStream.of(array[i]).map(n->{
            if(n<0) {
                return n*-1;
            }
            else {
                return n;
            }
        }).sum();
        a[i]=sum;


} return a;}
```

Here I just make all the negative Integers into Positive.

Answer (score 1):

Update this line
`int sum = IntStream.of(array[i]).sum();`
to
`int sum = IntStream.of(array[i]).map(Math::abs).sum();`

And solution for whole matrix (this snippet will return 23):

```
Optional<Integer> maxVal = Arrays.stream(matrix)
    .map(array -> Arrays.stream(array).map(Math::abs).sum())
    .reduce(Integer::max);
```

And without Optional

```
int maxVal = Arrays.stream(matrix)
    .map(array -> Arrays.stream(array).map(Math::abs).sum())
    .reduce(Integer::max).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
Math.abs(var)
```

This will turn var to a positive if it is negative.

Therefore the full answer is as follows:

```
public static int[] rowSums(int[][]array) {
int[] a = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        int sum = IntStream.of(array[i]).map(Math::abs).sum();
        a[i]=sum;


} return a;}
```

Comment: `Math.abs` doesn't take a `int[]` parameter. And you're not taking a max anywhere.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks I missed that. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.abs()`  It'll take any number and return it as a positive number.  You need it on this line:

```
int sum = IntStream.of(array[i]).sum();
```

to take `array[i]` and make it absolute.  So

```
IntStream.of(Math.abs(array[i]).sum();
```

Comment: @Andy Turner - I know, before you mention it.  Nice catch on them.

Answer (score 0):

Change all numbers to positive numbers. This can be done using `Math.abs(int)`.Check the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).